# Gatsbys render-page.js in the cache gets too big

Tags: babeljs, gatsby

After I upgraded to `Gatsby 4` I get the following error message during build and startup:

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /workspaces/gatsby-starter-dogmatism/.cache/page-ssr/routes/render-page.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
```

How to deal with this?

```
  System:
    OS: Linux 5.14 Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 10 (buster)
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    Shell: 5.0.3 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.8.0 - /tmp/yarn--1635514639979-0.49766755631091586/node
    Yarn: 1.22.5 - /tmp/yarn--1635514639979-0.49766755631091586/yarn
    npm: 7.21.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^4.0.2 => 4.0.2
    gatsby-plugin-emotion: ^7.0.0 => 7.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-image: ^2.0.0 => 2.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^4.0.1 => 4.0.1
    gatsby-remark-autolink-headers: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-remark-images: ^6.0.0 => 6.0.0
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-ts: ^1.0.0-rc.1 => 1.0.0-rc.1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't. I've migrated with most of my projects to Nextjs as Gatsby became more and more unstable.